# Possibly Wrong Equations of planes of Convex Hull using CGAL

Tags: computational-geometry, cgal, convex-hull

I am new to Computational Geometry. This may be a naive question. I have used CGAL to find convex hull of a set of points. Then I extract the planes for convex hull using the example code given on the CGAL website [here](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polyhedron/Polyhedron_2polyhedron_prog_planes_8cpp-example.html). The program is given below.

```
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/GMP/Gmpq_type.h>
#include <CGAL/Polyhedron_3.h>
#include <CGAL/convex_hull_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Side_of_triangle_mesh.h>
#include <CGAL/number_utils.h>
#include <iomanip>

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel Kernel;
typedef CGAL::Polyhedron_3<Kernel> Polyhedron_3;
typedef Kernel::Point_3 Point_3;
typedef Kernel::Plane_3 Plane_3;
typedef Kernel::Vector_3 Vector_3;
typedef CGAL::Side_of_triangle_mesh<Polyhedron_3, Kernel> Point_inside;

struct Plane_equation {
    template <class Facet>
    typename Facet::Plane_3 operator()( Facet& f) {
    typename Facet::Halfedge_handle h = f.halfedge();
    typedef typename Facet::Plane_3  Plane;
    return Plane( h->vertex()->point(),
              h->next()->vertex()->point(),
              h->next()->next()->vertex()->point());
    }
};

Point_3 create_point(std::string x, std::string y, std::string z) {
  Point_3 p;
  std::istringstream input(x + " " + y + " " + z);
  input >> p;
  return p;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<Point_3> points;
        points.push_back(create_point("-780692485006853753617237/10240000000000000000000000000",
                                      "-1563546083667768699030143/2500000000000000000000000",
                                      "0"));
        points.push_back(create_point("379213264894343110801237/10240000000000000000000000000",
                                      "-1563546083667768699030143/2500000000000000000000000",
                                      "0"));
        points.push_back(create_point("-780692485006853753617237/10240000000000000000000000000",
                                      "0",
                                      "0"));
        points.push_back(create_point("379213264894343110801237/10240000000000000000000000000",
                                      "-379213264894343110801237/10240000000000000000000000000",
                                      "0"));
        points.push_back(create_point("-780692485006853753617237/10240000000000000000000000000",
                                      "3223865085330535926726143/2500000000000000000000000",
                                      "-780692485006853753617237/10240000000000000000000000000"));
        points.push_back(create_point("379213264894343110801237/10240000000000000000000000000",
                                      "3223865085330535926726143/2500000000000000000000000",
                                      "379213264894343110801237/10240000000000000000000000000"));
        points.push_back(create_point("379213264894343110801237/10240000000000000000000000000",
                                      "0",
                                      "379213264894343110801237/10240000000000000000000000000"));
        points.push_back(create_point("-780692485006853753617237/10240000000000000000000000000",
                                      "780692485006853753617237/10240000000000000000000000000",
                                      "-780692485006853753617237/10240000000000000000000000000"));
        points.push_back(create_point("0", "0", "0"));
        
    Polyhedron_3 poly;
    CGAL::convex_hull_3(points.begin(), points.end(), poly);
    // CGAL::draw(poly);
    std::transform(poly.facets_begin(), poly.facets_end(), poly.planes_begin(), Plane_equation());
    CGAL::set_pretty_mode(std::cout);
    std::copy(poly.planes_begin(), poly.planes_end(),
                  std::ostream_iterator<Plane_3>(std::cout, "\n"));

    Point_inside inside_tester(poly);
    CGAL::Bounded_side res = inside_tester(Point_3(0, 0, 0));
    if (res == CGAL::ON_BOUNDED_SIDE) {
      std::cout << "Origin is inside" << "\n";
    } else if (res == CGAL::ON_BOUNDARY) {
      std::cout << "Origin is on the boundary" << "\n";
    } else {
      std::cout << "Origin is outside the polyhedron" << "\n";
    }

    for (auto it = poly.planes_begin(); it != poly.planes_end(); ++it) {
      std::cout << "A = " << it->a().exact() << "\n";
      std::cout << "B = " << it->b().exact() << "\n";
      std::cout << "C = " << it->c().exact() << "\n";
      std::cout << "D = " << it->d().exact() << "\n";
      std::cout << "\n";
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

After generating convex hull using `convex_hull_3`, I try to extract the plane equations for all the planes. Below is the output for the program

```
Plane_3(0, -4.19475e-09, 7.08424e-05, -2.62348e-09)
Plane_3(-4.76816e-05, 0, 0, -3.63522e-09)
Plane_3(4.76788e-05, 0, -7.08382e-05, -1.76567e-09)
Plane_3(-9.83085e-05, 0, 0, -7.49499e-09)
Plane_3(-0.00014607, 8.6358e-09, 0.00014607, -1.11363e-08)
Plane_3(9.83085e-05, 0, -0.000146061, -3.64062e-09)
Plane_3(0.000146074, 4.19475e-09, -0.000146074, -5.40933e-09)
Plane_3(0, -8.6358e-09, -7.08511e-05, -5.40099e-09)
Plane_3(-4.77552e-05, 0, 0.00014607, -3.64083e-09)
Plane_3(-2.31608e-05, 0, 7.08424e-05, -1.76577e-09)
Plane_3(4.77552e-05, 0, 0, -1.7685e-09)
Plane_3(2.31595e-05, 0, 0, -8.57654e-10)
Origin is inside
A = 0
B = -219925823194877128532786493609493825335102426169/52428800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
C = 906783046340871373991245871626108775814746030891/12800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
D = -343864159553760260821702206832186399183132849909762204558692676563012167/131072000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

A = -1220648677481324419677714143344481488159947374891/25600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
B = 0
C = 0
D = -952951249343224727578040741115129097199790308301319818242882753758596167/262144000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

A = 4999480934017386895980017109227629957533970363431367/104857600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
B = 0
C = -3713963431989014270739610303686932051911864640103367/52428800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
D = -1895869487765753248495994462519358098874827535092392449815572846416028200979/1073741824000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

A = -10308396833918147444194565967124294714798768363431367/104857600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
B = 0
C = 0
D = -8047687940708342026893035469747920357861814098710951530122415210209637672979/1073741824000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

A = -1869689824690300646434385556309825774908173982891/12800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
B = 452764851132051796393052935016376879217993818169/52428800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
C = 1869689824690300646434385556309825774908173982891/12800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
D = -1459652795429499560461049209852394023543048968469784428121757724600692167/131072000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

A = 10308396833918147444194565967124294714798768363431367/104857600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
B = 0
C = -7657796757080339395998850185710029997144662640103367/52428800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
D = -3909080819216610292966257636154114768379010997867208966773927801542028200979/1073741824000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

A = 1531693889550933264984755205027731173569843147269541/10485760000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
B = 219925823194877128532786493609493825335102426169/52428800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
C = -1531693889550933264984755205027731173569843147269541/10485760000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
D = -709011182760540911322636241675226035790615443402528424913924328539636167/131072000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

A = 0
B = -452764851132051796393052935016376879217993818169/52428800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
C = -742927224532668239932907228623111584523283547269541/10485760000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
D = -707918709809939897610498041142184898705751664465632699646023679792068167/131072000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

A = -1222532404587072576861092389210725463247004638891/25600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
B = 0
C = 1869689824690300646434385556309825774908173982891/12800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
D = -954421860938486024795167813392498809224920480657508534678004510218164167/262144000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

A = -592917415200418328304777599907736063469544686891/25600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
B = 0
C = 906783046340871373991245871626108775814746030891/12800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
D = -462886170276655067642955341169240700211713020629945581049164605825540167/262144000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

A = 1222532404587072576861092389210725463247004638891/25600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
B = 0
C = 0
D = -463600504582595797850104669957953262356310406147548315149844146861108167/262144000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

A = 2428445929960641645499203498146234146289758916775367/104857600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
B = 0
C = 0
D = -920898909719754197337687026347401189092620563028663434317768459371714728979/1073741824000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

You can notice the line which says that origin is inside the convex hull. Now if the origin is inside the convex hull, then if I check the side of origin relative to a plane by checking `0*a + 0*b + 0*c + d`, then for some planes, the output should be positive and for some it should be negative. But in this case, the outputs (essentially the d value) is negative for all planes. What is it that I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Why do you believe that the signs should change? Note that planes (a,b,c,d) and (-a,-b,-c,-d) are the same.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Sure. But I didn't find anything explicitly mentioned in the documentation and I don't have any other sources to cross check. Can you suggest something which I can use to verify the equations?